# Freebase MQLWrite Login Fail 401 Gone

Tags: authentication, freebase, http-status-code-410

I am trying to write to freebase. I read this documentation:
[documentation](http://mql.freebaseapps.com/ch06.html)

and tried login to both 
https://api.freebase.com/api/account/login

but am getting (410) Gone error.

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That API endpoint was retired some time ago.  Check the [current documentation](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/mql-overview) for the new endpoints.

Comment: so if I understand correctly these days there is no need for login?

Comment: You may need to authenticate using OAuth2 for certain operations, but most operations just require an API key.  The old Metaweb Freebase style login is no longer used.

Comment: After Reading about OAuth2 I created a project in the Goolge Developers console and got credentials for service account, with Client Id. tried using the following url via webClient to connect: 
[basic links] https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=someNumbersForClientId.apps.googleusercontent.com
but keep getting 400 Bad Request.
What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: When running the url directly in browser I get :
Missing required "response_type" parameter Error